# How to write the query to select data when another select is matched

Tags: mysql

TableA

```
Id, DateTime1
1, 2020-10-10
2, 2020-10-11
3, 2020-10-12
```

TableB

```
Id, Status
1, 1
1, 2
3, 1
```

If I want to select all the row from **TableA**, where the `DateTime1` between 2020-10-10 to 2020-10-12, If any row in **TableA** in this time period having Status in **TableB** is 1 or 2, How could I write this query?

The expected result for (2020-10-10 to 2020-10-12 and any one row is status 1 or 2) will be as below:

```
Id, DateTime1
1, 2020-10-10
2, 2020-10-11
3, 2020-10-12
```

If I change the Status to (2020-10-10 to 2020-10-12 and any one row is status 3), then no row will be selected, as there is no any row on this period having status 3..

If I write

```
select * 
from TableA as A 
inner join TableB as B on A.Id = B.Id 
where A.DateTime1 >= '2020-10-10' 
  and A.DateTime1 <= '2020-10-12' 
  and B.Status = 1 
  or B.Status = 2
```

then only Id, 1 and 3 are selected, but I want  1, 2 and 3.

If I write:

```
select * 
from TableA, (select count(A.id) 
              from TableA as A 
              inner join TableB as B on A.Id = B.Id 
              where A.DateTime1 >= '2020-10-10' 
                and A.DateTime1 <= '2020-10-12' 
                and B.Status = 1 
                or B.Status = 2) as totals 
where DateTime1 >= '2020-10-10' 
  and DateTime1 <= '2020-10-12' 
  and totals  > 0
```

there is error failed : `Unknown column 'totals' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Specify link between tables (by foreign key). Expand the sample data maybe... And show desired output for provided data.

Comment: Study carefully: [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html).

Comment: *there is error failed : Unknown column 'totals' in 'where clause'* Of course - `totals` is subquery alias, not column alias.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a subquery. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id from TableB WHERE Status>=1 AND Status<=2)
```

This will select all rows in TableA with status between 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. According to given data, I assumed that TableA and TableB have a foreign key relationship with `id` column.

```
select a.* from TableA a
join TableB b on a.id = b.id
where a.DateTime1 >= '2020-10-10' and a.DateTime1 <= '2020-10-12'
and b.Status in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be my question cannot explain it correctly. I found the solution, But is there any better solution?

select * from TableA where DateTime1 >= '2020-10-10' and DateTime1 <= '2020-10-12' and (select count(A.id) from TableA as A inner join TableB as B on A.Id = B.Id where A.DateTime1 >= '2020-10-10' and A.DateTime1 <= '2020-10-12' and B.Status = 1) > 0

The first select will now only select if there is any rows on that time period matched the status and time period).

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
select * 
from TableA as A , TableB as B 
where  A.Id = B.Id 
AND (A.DateTime1 >= '2020-10-10' AND A.DateTime1 <= '2020-10-12' )
AND (B.Status = 1 or B.Status = 2)
```

OR

```
select * 
from TableA as A , TableB as B 
where  A.Id = B.Id 
AND (A.DateTime1 >= '2020-10-10' AND A.DateTime1 <= '2020-10-12' )
AND CASE WHEN B.Status IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
```